# has_many through with :class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, relationships

I have the following:

```
belongs_to :type, :class_name => :activity_type
belongs_to :activity_type # needed for has_one :through?
has_one :category, :through => :activity_type, :class_name => :activity_category
```

Is there a way to do this "has_one through" relationship using "type" instead of "activity_type"?

**Edit: This was not working, and I failed to see thanks to the magic word "type".**

What I have now is this:

```
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :type, :class_name => 'ActivityType', :foreign_key => 'activity_type_id'
  has_one :category, :through => :type, :class_name => 'ActivityCategory', :foreign_key => 'activity_category_id'
```

But it fails with

```
  no such column: activity_types.category_id
```

which is correct, since the expected column would be "activity_types.activity_category_id". How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using associations in a wrong way. First of all when you use `through:` then `class_name`, `foreign_key` [will be omitted](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one). So this is why it's expecting `category_id`. Also I think that you shouldn't overload your associations with rewriting defaults options since when there's a lot of associations on a model it starts to look like a mess and hard to understand. So you probably should just write it as `belongs_to :activity_type` and add whatever name suits you best like `alias_method :type, :activity_type`.

So in short, this is what I'm proposing you:

```
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :activity_type
has_one :activity_category, :through => :activity_type

alias_method :type, :activity_type
alias_method :category, :activity_category
```

Comment: Thanks, alias_method is what I was looking for.